# Create all combinations of two sets of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am trying to create all combinations of two sets of lists using as follows:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
y = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

combos  = [[1,2,3,'a','b','c'],[4,5,6,'d','e','f'],[4,5,6,'a','b','c'],[4,5,6,'d','e','f']]
```

I think itertools may be of some help but not sure how. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `product` and `chain`:

```
from itertools import product, chain
[list(chain(*i)) for i in product(x, y)]

#[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
# [1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f'],
# [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
# [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

---

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
[i + j for i in x for j in y]

#[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
# [1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f'],
# [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
# [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```